# What is the difference between tick() and flush() in angular testing?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, ionic-framework, jasmine

On the angular documentation I see these two functions, [`tick()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) and [`flush()`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush). Both of these seem to do similar things. From the angular documentation, it says for tick:

> Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone.

and for flush:

> Simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone by draining the macrotask queue until it is empty. The returned value is the milliseconds of time that would have been elapsed.

Can anyone explain the difference to me?

EDIT (answered in the comments):

In addition, in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service) `tick()` is used without parameters, and the comment on that line even uses the phrase "flush"

```js
it('should display error when TwainService fails', fakeAsync(() => {
  // tell spy to return an error observable
  getQuoteSpy.and.returnValue(
    throwError('TwainService test failure'));

  fixture.detectChanges(); // onInit()
  // sync spy errors immediately after init

  tick(); // flush the component's setTimeout()

  fixture.detectChanges(); // update errorMessage within setTimeout()

  expect(errorMessage()).toMatch(/test failure/, 'should display error');
  expect(quoteEl.textContent).toBe('...', 'should show placeholder');
}));
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They do different things relative to async operations that were *previously started*. For example; calling `setTimeout(...)` starts an async operation.

- `tick()` moves *time* forward.
- `flush()` moves *time* to the end.

This can be better illustrated with the unit tests for those functions.

### Tick

This unit test shows tick being used to move time forward in *steps* until all *10* timers have finished. Tick is called multiple times.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/test/fake_async_spec.ts#L205

```
      it('should clear periodic timers', fakeAsync(() => {
           let cycles = 0;
           const id = setInterval(() => { cycles++; }, 10);

           tick(10);
           expect(cycles).toEqual(1);

           discardPeriodicTasks();

           // Tick once to clear out the timer which already started.
           tick(10);
           expect(cycles).toEqual(2);

           tick(10);
           // Nothing should change
           expect(cycles).toEqual(2);
         }));
```

### Flush

This unit test shows that all async tasks should be finished when it returns, and that the returned value tells you how long it took for them to finish.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/test/fake_async_spec.ts#L273

```
      it('should flush multiple tasks', fakeAsync(() => {
           let ran = false;
           let ran2 = false;
           setTimeout(() => { ran = true; }, 10);
           setTimeout(() => { ran2 = true; }, 30);

           let elapsed = flush();

           expect(ran).toEqual(true);
           expect(ran2).toEqual(true);
           expect(elapsed).toEqual(30);
         }));
```

Comment: That makes sense, but from the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-with-async-service), using tick() without any parameters seems to effectively do a flush.

Comment: @JustinKavalan yeah, I read that too. So basically without a parameter it means that the `tick()` moves *all* the way forward. So it is the same as a `flush()`. The difference is that `tick()` doesn't return how much time elapsed.

Comment: @JustinKavalan if this answers your question. Please accept it as the answer.

Comment: I just wanted to add that `tick()` and `flush()` are not equal. I have a test where I spy `router.navigate` inside a subscription triggered by a click, and using `tick()` leaves a periodic timer in the queue whereas `flush()` doesn't.
(Interestingly `flush()` always returns 500 ms in this test.)

Comment: I thought that `tick()` with no arguments just runs immediate timers, like `setTimeout(() => doSomething(), 0)`.  `flush()` is basically `while(testZone.hasPendingTasks) { tick(1); }`

Comment: Just to also clarify for future readers, because we have conflicting information in the comments above me: `tick()` without parameters IS NOT the same as `flush()`. Coderer is correct, `tick()` runs just the outstanding tasks, which means timeouts and intervals with a value > 0 are not processed by `tick()`. See answer from Angular dev: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/43625#issuecomment-930164269

Answer (score 0):

As of Angular 15, [tick](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) and [flush](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush) call Zone.js's [FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/67f0cf5fc8a2be4a48c6cd15db53ce9c9c4cd014/packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts#L127).

- `tick` and `flush` [flush all microtasks first](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/b11bd466c20dc338b6d4d5bc3e59868ff263778d/lib/zone-spec/fake-async-test.ts#L400), e.g. `Promise.then` and `queueMicrotask`.
- `tick` has a [default tick count of 0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/67f0cf5fc8a2be4a48c6cd15db53ce9c9c4cd014/packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts#L122), defined by Angular in milliseconds. It executes macrotasks, including periodic tasks like `setInterval`, [scheduled up to the current time plus the tick count](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/b11bd466c20dc338b6d4d5bc3e59868ff263778d/lib/zone-spec/fake-async-test.ts#L135).

  - Therefore, by default `tick` only executes the tasks scheduled up to but not at the current time.
- `flush` has a [default turn count of 20](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/67f0cf5fc8a2be4a48c6cd15db53ce9c9c4cd014/packages/core/testing/src/fake_async.ts#L143), defined by the Zone.js fake async test scheduler. It executes macrotasks, but not periodic tasks, [up to the turn count number of tasks (which is treated as the limit) or the first periodic task](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/b11bd466c20dc338b6d4d5bc3e59868ff263778d/lib/zone-spec/fake-async-test.ts#L187).

  - Therefore, by default `flush` executes macrotasks up until the first periodic task or a maximum of 20.
  - If there are more than the limit number of tasks, `flush` throws an error.

See [async.spec.ts](https://github.com/TrevorKarjanis/angular-async-test-specs?tab=readme-ov-file) for a complete set of example tests.

```js
it('tick executes all microtasks and macrotasks', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpy('interval');
  zone.runTask(() => queueMicrotask(() => { }));
  zone.runTask(() => setInterval(spy, 1));
  zone.runTask(() => queueMicrotask(() => { }));
  expect(zone.hasPendingMicrotasks).toBeTrue();
  expect(zone.hasPendingMacrotasks).toBeTrue();

  tick(1);
  expect(zone.hasPendingMicrotasks).toBeFalse();
  expect(zone.hasPendingMacrotasks).toBeTrue();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith();

  discardPeriodicTasks();
}));

it('flush executes all microtasks and non-periodic macrotasks', fakeAsync(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpy('interval');
  zone.runTask(() => queueMicrotask(() => { }));
  zone.runTask(() => setTimeout(spy));
  zone.runTask(() => queueMicrotask(() => { }));
  expect(zone.hasPendingMicrotasks).toBeTrue();
  expect(zone.hasPendingMacrotasks).toBeTrue();

  flush();
  expect(zone.hasPendingMicrotasks).toBeFalse();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith();
}));
```